# How to Deploying an existing WCF service to Azure?

Tags: azure

I want to use Azure as deployment server for your existing WCF service. Could anybody help me out how and steps for that.

Comment: This is super-broad. And it's unclear what, exactly, you're asking. "Deployment Server"? Are you looking to run a build service? If it's about running a WCF service, there are *many* ways to do that (which is why this question is really broad and opinion-based and, as it is currently written, off-topic).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Azure or How to Deploying an existing WCF service to Azure? Then you just need to follow simple steps. Here are the steps to do that ... http://www.advaiya.com/blog/deploying-an-existing-wcf-service-to-azure

Comment: Thanks John   I have visited the #Advaiya link that you have mention. Its all about the same that i am looking for..